# How to determine the meaning of nil in clojure?

Tags: clojure

for example,

```
> (some #{nil} #{nil 1 2 3})
nil

> (some #{} #{nil 1 2 3})
nil
```

I know I could use

```
(some nil? #{nil 1 2 3})
```

to check nil value. I can't think of any good example at the moment.

But generally, when nil is returned， how do I determine if nil means nothing is found or the value nil is found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nil` is just a value, and its meaning depends on context.

It's just like all other values in that regard: the only thing to be aware of is that it is `falsy`, i.e. counts as `false` in conditional expressions.

Three particular cases to be aware of:

- `nil` is the return value used to indicate an empty sequence, e.g. in `(seq [])`
- `nil` is often used as a return value to indicate false, e.g. in `(or false nil)`
- `nil` is returned by default when a map lookup can't find a given key, e.g. in `({:a 1} :b)`

These cases can on occasion cause ambiguity: if so then you need to use a different function. Your example is a good one:

- `(some #{nil} #{1 2 3})` => `nil` (failure - no result found)
- `(some #{nil} #{nil 1 2 3})` => `nil` (success - nil result found!!!)

In this case you've simply chosen the wrong function: you can't use the set `#{nil}` to detect nils.... instead you can just use `nil?` or you could even do something fancy with an alternative return value like `#(get #{nil} % :not-found)`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a question of the question you're asking, rather than anything particular to Clojure ?

You could ask:

```
> (filter nil? #{nil 1 2 3})
> (nil)
```

which tells you there was one nil in the set; you get what you ask for - you asked an ambiguous question and got a suitably ambiguous response.